# RaphaelJS scale path in one direction only

Tags: svg, raphael

I have a path that I am resizing via a scale transform. However, it scales it in both directions (left and right). I want to scale it just to the right. Is there something I need to do in the transform string to accomplish this? Right now, all I have is:

```
objectToMove.transform("...s1.01");
```

I'm using a drag event to scale it, so it's scaling by a factor of 1.01 as long as you're dragging it.

Side question: Is it possible to resize by a fixed number of pixels rather than a scale factor?

Comment: To prevent this, you record the mousedown value, (Xo,Yo), on mouse move event, read (X-move, Y-move) and if Y-move > Yo, then scale Raphael image.

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. The problem is that the scale transform scales the path both to the left and to the right, rather than just to the right. It almost seems like I need to set the center of the transform axis to the leftmost point of the path or something, if that makes sense.

Comment: You have a fiddle example? Easier to fix by looking at code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4vLjbyy5/3/ If you hover over the right end of a line the cursor will change and then you can drag to resize.

Comment: Have you tried [freetransform](http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/)? It has `range` and `scale` limits built in, saves you a fair bit of coding.

Comment: I have not seen that before. I'll give it a shot and maybe I can get rid of most of my transform code. Thanks!